# Proper practice of switching between user controls in an ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Consider the following scenario:

I have a .aspx page without two .ascx(s). One of which contains search functionalities, while the other user control is responsible for user input. 
Now I have a "Create" button located inside the first user control (search) that allows users to create new records from the second user control. Currently, this is what I have been doing.

```
//initial state
UserControlA (Search) - Visible="true"
UserControlB (Create) - Visible="false"
```

```
protected btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControlA.visible = false;
    UserControlB.visible = true;
}
```

In this case, my user controls are switched between the first and the second. However, this is posted whereby whenever user hits the refresh button, a "confirm form resubmission" alert box is shown.

What is the best practice in having to **switch user controls on the same page url** without having the form resubmission whenever a user hits the refresh button?

Comment: To be clear, you are wanting to hide/show different controls without posting back to the server?

Comment: Yes. I want the user to stay on the same page with different user controls without GET request

Comment: As this is client side, Javascript (with jQuery?) would be the sensible thing to use.

Comment: I prefer not to use Javascript with all the `display:none` and `display:block` property.